# Ways to display data in an HTML page from DB using Servlets

Tags: java, html, servlets

Is there a way other than what I have below using Servlets to display data in HTML page?

```
response.setContentType("text/html");
PrintWriter info = response.getWriter();
info.println("then creating table and displaying data");
info.close();
```

I have already checked many threads in different sites, but most of them suggest JSTL and JSP or what I have above.

I'm looking for other ways to display data in HTML from a Servlet.

Comment: You can use a Template Engine. What is wrong with JSPs?

Comment: JSP ultimately converted to Servlet. Not a good way to build the HTML in Servlet itself. It tightly binds the business logic with presentation logic.

Comment: JSP is mostly used as presentation same as HTML.

Comment: Is there any particular reason why you don't want to use a template language?